# Stuck recovering what appears to be a seed for a wallet

Tags: wallet-recovery, paper-wallet, seed

I've been passed a piece of text from my father who's not really interested in the crypto space. He claims he bought a fraction of a coin a few years ago (about 4) and placed the wallet on a paper wallet.

I've asked him where he generated this wallet from but he cannot remember that. I've tried to recover this wallet using various versions of Electrum, but none worked.

Is there anyone out here that would be able to recognize this seed pattern and point me into the direction in which it can be recovered?

The pattern looks like so:

`mywallet xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx yyyyyyyyyyy`

The x are random letters/integers and the y looks like a potential password to unlock the file (100% sure the Y was typed by him and not generated). Googling "mywallet" brings back results with blockchain but I cannot recovery it there as the seed is not 12 words long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like information for a blockchain.info wallet. The x's are the wallet id and the y's are probably the password. Go to blockchain.info's wallet login page and enter the string of x's (with dashes) in the wallet id part and the string of y's in the password part.

Comment: Hm, I think you may be right. I'm having difficulty logging in. I'm not getting a message that the id/password is incorrect, it's just... hanging... Tried with 2 browsers and cleared cache on both. Entering an incorrect password returns the "Password incorrect" message. I guess I'll contact support. Thanks for helping identify this!